# DDMS unable to see Google Glass

Tags: adb, ddms, google-glass

I am trying to get Eclipse and DDMS to see my Google Glass device. I have followed the instructions found here:

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start

However the DDMS device list is still empty no matter what I do. I have tried multiple USB ports and different cables. The Device Manager can see the Glass device but the DDMS doesn't. The DDMS can see emulators however.

After doing a little digging it seems that you need to make sure that a driver is installed for actual devices vs emulators. However I can't find any instructions on how to do that with Google Glass. I tried installed the generic Google USB driver however that wouldn't install for the Glass device. I am running all of this on Windows 8.1, though I can't seem to find anything where that would make a difference. I am wondering if anyone else has had this problem or can offer any advise.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*First* - Disable driver signature enforcement for Windows 8. Google for a buffet of how-to tutorials/instructions, if you don't already know.

*Second* - Update android_winusb.inf file @

*Example:* C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

```
[Google.NTamd64]

;GoogleGlass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01

[Google.NTx86]

;GoogleGlass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

Once inf file is edited, go into your Windows Device Manager, right click on the Glass Device, select Update Driver Software. When prompted, choose "Select From Computer" and enter your android_winusb.inf parent folder location.

**NOTE:** During Driver Update you may receive an unsigned driver warning; you must proceed with the unsigned driver to succeed.

Open eclipse. If you don't see the Glass device in DDMS perspective right off, run your application/sample as an Android Application and the device should be available as an selectable option during an Android Device Chooser dialog (Provided Glass is running with debug on and plugged into the machine).

Comment: So I've made some progress per your help matthew, thank you. I disabled the driver signature and updated the android_winusb.inf file per your instruction. Now when I go to install the driver I am getting an error that says "The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering." Any more ideas? Any chance we left something out?

Comment: so this worked but i had to do this on win 8.1 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556137/google-glass-isnt-showing-up-as-a-device-on-eclipse-under-ddms-help-please/20635256#20635256)  

With Glass connected, Eclipse running and DDMS visible (not sure if this really matters):

Open Windows Device manager

Expand Android Device

Right click on "Android Composite ADB Interface" and choose "Uninstall"

Disconnect Glass and then reconnect

Android Composite ADB Interface should reappear in Device Manager

After these steps google-glass appeared in my DDMS.

Comment: I too got this error: "The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering." It turned out that I needed to disable driver signature enforcement again, even though I've done it before (it must have re-enabled when I got 8.1). There are plenty of instructions on how to do this online, but I used this: http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/

Comment: After doing the above (on a Win 8.1 laptop) device manager now shows "Android ADB Interface" and no longer shows Glass as it did before I followed these instructions.  Also, previously the glass showed up as a 12GB removeable drive whereas now it no longer does.  In either case it does NOT show up in DDMS.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

matthew06854's solution works well! Thanks. Just one thing, after connecting glass to the computer, one needs to confirm on the glass to allow this connection (trusted computer, or something like it).

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to check that VID and PID matches what you see in Control Panel/System/Device Manager/Portable Devices/Glass 1/Properties/Details/Hardware Ids. I only got USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216 and USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001, so I changed the file \adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver to reflect this:

```
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

Since I had already installed first version og the driver I had to remove driver before I could install with new settings. Now it works for me also :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way
Download these custmized drivers from
http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22979706399752791

Then go to device manager look for glass-right click-update divers-custom brows location and provide the path of above folder

This link really helped me
http://appliedanalog.com/agw/?p=17

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing step here ,that I figured out.
In my case, my andriod_winusb.inf already had some values under the ;Google Glass line.
That made the Google Glass device appear in the device manager, but as an "Android ADB Interface" instead of an "Android Composite ADB Interface".
Any changes to the andriod_winusb.inf didn't make any difference.

What worked for me was to click on the Andid ADB Interface in the Device Manager. Click uninstall, and (very important) check the check box that says : "Delete the driver software for this device".

Then I modified the andriod_winusb.inf file, and clicked on Glass 1 in the Device manager, and updated the driver.

I'm guessing that once Windows knows about a driver, it caches it somewhere, so uninstalling it and reinstalling ,without "deleting the driver software" just brings the cached driver back, and completely disregards the changes in the original driver folder.