# Google Glass isn't showing up as a device on eclipse under DDMS.

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass

I edited the .inf file in my C:adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver directory.

I installed the drivers for Windows 7 through that same directory.

My Google Glass is in debug mode.

**The device is plugged in, yet it isn't showing up in my DDMS Devices list?** Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to install the driver by following the steps in [matthew06854](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3046253/matthew06854)'s post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390624/ddms-unable-to-see-google-glass/20412429#20412429).

Although the driver seemed to install correctly, I could not see the device under DDMS in Eclipse.

I was finally able to get Glass to show up under Eclipse DDMS on Windows 8.1.

With Glass connected, Eclipse running and DDMS visible (not sure if this really matters):

1. Open Windows Device manager
2. Expand Android Device
3. Right click on "Android Composite ADB Interface" and choose
   "Uninstall"
4. Disconnect Glass and then reconnect
5. Android Composite ADB Interface should reappear in Device Manager

After these steps google-glass appeared in my DDMS.